# How to set numerous links in a single line with CSS?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make a bar on the top of the page, but am unsure of how to make all links fall on the same line.

This is what I have:

```css
#tb {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
    width: 60px;
}
```

```html
<div class id="tb">
  <a href="homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="newslink">News</a>
  <a href="contactlink">Contact</a>
  <a href="aboutlink">About</a>
</div>
```

I've tried removing many combinations in the CSS, but so far nothing. If the answer is incredibly obvious, please excuse my ignorance, as I am new to CSS.

Thanks,

-Tysuna

Comment: Consider: `display: inline-block; float:left;`. BTW, why not using `ul`,`li` (semantics speaking)?

Comment: use display: inline;

Also, i would change the div to a ul and each a would then be an li as suggested above

Comment: this article will help you http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_navbar.asp

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/soledar10/pt22767s/

Comment: Wow, many wrongs here : 1) for lists, use `<ol>` or `<ul>` tag combined with `<li>`. 2) ideally href should be a real URL, not a placeholder for same variable you might be using in js. 3) using id's as CSS selector is bad practice because of high specificity. Select preferably by class, not by ID.

Comment: I was initially using lists, but somehow encountered many more problems with them in the rest of the document than I did with this, so I decided to remove it (at least until I get better at using them and sorting their problems out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use some flexbox magic:

```css
#tb {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}
```

```html
<div class id="tb">
  <a href="homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="newslink">News</a>
  <a href="contactlink">Contact</a>
  <a href="aboutlink">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: @Tysuna Add some margin, e.g. `#tb > a { margin: 0 5px }`

Comment: it's worth mentionning felxbox [isn't supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox) in previous versions of IE

Answer (score 3):

You've set a `width` on `#tb` which is causing the `a`s inside it to wrap to new lines. The `a` tags will automatically be placed on the same line as they are classed as `inline` elements.

> Inline-level elements are those elements of the source document that do not form new blocks of content; the content is distributed in lines (e.g., emphasized pieces of text within a paragraph, inline images, etc.).

(http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-boxes)

Removing the `width` will allow the `div` to fill the entire width of its container (as it is a `block` element).

> A block-level element occupies the entire space of its parent element (container), thereby creating a "block."

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Block-level_elements)

As `#tb` is now as wide as the body the `a` tags will be on the same line, only wrapping if the window size is decreased enough.

```css
#tb {
    text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div class id="tb">
  <a href="homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="newslink">News</a>
  <a href="contactlink">Contact</a>
  <a href="aboutlink">About</a>
</div>
```

*Your CSS in this particular example can also be simplified as many of the properties specified are already defaults, not applicable or would have no effect.*

Answer (score 1):

Update: specifiy for a-tag separatly, isntead of inheritance

```css
#tb {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: block; /*property will be inherited by 'a'-tag elements too*/
    width: 60px;
} 
#tb a{
 display: inline-block; /* specifiy for a-tag separatly*/
}
```

```html
<div class id="tb">
  <a href="homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="newslink">News</a>
  <a href="contactlink">Contact</a>
  <a href="aboutlink">About</a>
</div>
```

Comment: This works just because `width` does not apply to inline elements. Removing the `width` as [Adam](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30914649/1529630) or [Hidden Hobbes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30914664/1529630) say would make more sense.

Answer (score 0):

Check the below code.

You can use explicitly `display:inline-block` or `display:inline` to make any element to stay in the same line.But Here if you remove the width thats enough.

Instead of `div` structure better use `ul` which will make your job easier.Bydefault it will align in a line.

```css
#tb {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
   
}
```

```html
<div class id="tb">
  <a href="homelink">Home</a>
  <a href="newslink">News</a>
  <a href="contactlink">Contact</a>
  <a href="aboutlink">About</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

remove `width: 60px`  - #tb

use   `ul li` and `display: inline-block` for `li`

```css
#tb {
    list-style-type: none;
    position:relative;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0;    
    text-align: center;
    display: block;    
} 
#tb > li{
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: top;   
    margin: 0 5px;
}
```

```html
<ul id="tb">
    <li><a href="homelink">Home</a></li>
    <li><a href="newslink">News</a></li>
    <li><a href="contactlink">Contact</a></li>
    <li><a href="aboutlink">About</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: This works because you removed `width`, not because you added `inline-block`.

Comment: @Oriol Yes you are right. but I changed the layout using a list.